# How do I keep the width and the height of cells the same using CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm using `auto-fill` for the columns of my grid. But some times the width of the cells is greater than their height.

Is there a way to keep them squared? While the width increases the height also increases.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
    background: salmon;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
<ul>
```

To illustrate my problem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: don't define grid-auto-rows, use the padding trick to keep the ratio

Answer (score 2):

I think, that you have to use just:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);`

instead of

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr);`

Comment: Good answer, but you better use Snippet tool to show the working example

Comment: But it will create some gaps along the edge. I wish they can fill all the available space and also keep the aspect ratio.